# Function Being Called Before Current Function Code Complete

Tags: javascript

Made a JS Fiddle implementation of the "5 hunters, 3 rabbits" problem described here: https://twitter.com/Mathgarden/status/1039247616616194048

## My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/iPrash/o037fpam/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rabbit Hunters</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="htmltable.css">

    <script language="JavaScript">
      var size = 5;
      var hunters = new Array();
      var arena = new Array(side, side);

      function hunter(row, col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
      }

      function hunter(row, col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
      }

      function resetArena() {
        hunters = [];
        redrawArena();
      }

      function generate_table() {
        // get the reference for the body
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
        var tbl = document.createElement("table");
        tbl.setAttribute("class", "huntertable");
        var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        // creating all cells
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          // creates a table row
          var row = document.createElement("tr");

          for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
            // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
            // the end of the table row
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.addEventListener("click", cellClicked);
            cell.bgColor = "green";
            cell.innerHTML = "O";
            row.appendChild(cell);
          }

          // add the row to the end of the table body
          tblBody.appendChild(row);
        }

        // put the <tbody> in the <table>
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        // appends <table> into <body>
        body.appendChild(tbl);
        // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
        tbl.setAttribute("border", "5");
      }

      function cellClicked() {

        var cellRow = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var cellCol = this.cellIndex;
        var cHunter = new hunter(cellRow, cellCol);

        if (exists(cHunter)) {
          // remove the hunter 
          remove(cHunter);

        } else {

          if (hunters.length == 5) {
            alert("A maximum of 5 hunters are allowed!");
            return;
          }

          hunters.push(cHunter);
          redrawArena();
        }
      }

      function exists(hunter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < hunters.length; i++) {
          if ((hunters[i].row == hunter.row) && (hunters[i].col == hunter.col))
            return true;
        }
        return false;

      }

      function remove(hunter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < hunters.length; i++) {
          if ((hunters[i].row == hunter.row) && (hunters[i].col == hunter.col)) {
            hunters.splice(i, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
        redrawArena();
      }

      function redrawArena() {

        var arenaTable = document.getElementsByTagName("tbl")[0];
        var arenaTBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        // reset arena
        for (var rowi = 0; rowi < size; rowi++) {
          for (var coli = 0; coli < size; coli++) {
            rRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[rowi];
            rCell = rRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[coli];
            rCell.innerHTML = "O";
            rCell.bgColor = "green";
          }
        }

        for (var hunterIndex = 0; hunterIndex < hunters.length; hunterIndex++) {
          // for each hunter mark the attacked territory:
          hunterRow = hunters[hunterIndex].row;
          hunterCol = hunters[hunterIndex].col;

          huntRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow];
          huntCell = huntRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol];
          huntCell.innerHTML = "H";
          huntCell.bgColor = "red";

          // horizontal and vertical
          for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            hRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow];
            hCell = hRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[i];
            hCell.bgColor = "red";

            vRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
            vCell = vRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol];
            vCell.bgColor = "red";
          }

          // diagonals
          for (var i = 1; i < size; i++) {

            if (((hunterRow + i) < size) && ((hunterCol + i) < size)) {
              dRow1 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow + i];
              dCell1 = dRow1.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol + i];
              dCell1.bgColor = "red";
            }

            if (((hunterRow - i) >= 0) && ((hunterCol - i) >= 0)) {
              dRow2 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow - i];
              dCell2 = dRow2.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol - i];
              dCell2.bgColor = "red";
            }

            if (((hunterRow + i) < size) && ((hunterCol - i) >= 0)) {
              dRow3 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow + i];
              dCell3 = dRow3.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol - i];
              dCell3.bgColor = "red";
            }

            if (((hunterRow - i) >= 0) && ((hunterCol + i) < size)) {
              dRow4 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow - i];
              dCell4 = dRow4.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol + i];
              dCell4.bgColor = "red";
            }
          }
        }
        alert("Checking for win ...");
        checkWin();
      }

      function checkWin() {
        // check arena for 5 hunters and 3 rabbits...
        if (hunters.length < 5)
            return;

                var arenaTable = document.getElementsByTagName("tbl")[0];
                var arenaTBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        var rabbits = 0;
        for (var rowi = 0; rowi < size; rowi++) {
          for (var coli = 0; coli < size; coli++) {
            rRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[rowi];
            rCell = rRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[coli];
            if (rCell.bgColor == "green") {
                rabbits++;            
            }

          }
        }
        if (rabbits == 3)
            alert("Congrats! You did it!")
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="generate_table()">
    <h1>Rabbit Hunters</h1>
    <p>
      <ol>
        <li>The grid below represents a forest filled with rabbits (green).</li>
        <li>Hunters can attack horizontally and diagonally in all directions (like a chess queen).</li>
        <li>Once placed, hunters will kill all rabbits in their lines of sight (try clicking!).</li>
        <li>To remove hunters just click on them again.</li>
        <li>The Reset button clears the whole forest.</li>
      </ol>
      <strong>Can you place 5 hunters on the grid below so that they spare 3 rabbits (three green squares should remain)?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetArena()" />
    </p>
  </body>

</html>
```

======================

My question is: Why does the alert "Checking for win ..." show up before the last hunter is drawn (or the arena is fully redrawn). I added this debug alert because even though I have the checkWin() function being called *after* the redraw loop is fully complete it seems to want to start executing checkWin() first. So the last clicked hunter square turns to "H" only after the alert while I want it to be before checking for win.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About problem

Your function `checkWin` isn't really invoked before any other code in function `redrawArena`. Described problem is caused by usage of code, that is blocking main UI thread of browser, which is used for updating rendered document and executing its JS code (except workers). So if you dynamically change properties (like CSS styles) of some elements in document, browser might not repaint (or reflow) document immediately, this will usually happen after all JS functions already present in call stack are popped out from it (i.e. they return value). Let us call some part of function code as "blocking code", if it will prevent this function from returning its value for longer time (long enough to make website noticeable unresponsive to user). Most common sources of blocking code are synchronous XMLHttpRequests, native JS dialogs, long running loops (e.g. some heavy computation), etc.

Here is a simple example demonstrating how will longer running loop (after first color change) block repainting of document, so you will never see "busy status" (red color):

```css
#status {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function start(){
        setStatus('red');
        compute();
      }
      
      function compute(){
        var a = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i+=0.000001){
          a.push(Math.sin(i) + Math.cos(i));
        }
        setStatus('green');
      }
      
      function setStatus(color){
        document.getElementById('status').style.backgroundColor = color;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Status: <div id="status"></div></div>
    <button onclick="start()">Compute</button>
    <button onclick="setStatus(null)">Reset</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Alert modal

Obviously, such a thread blocking behavior in your code can be caused only by `alert()` calls. But here arises question - Which browser(s) are you using for testing your code? According to [alert spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert):

> 6. Show message to the user.
> 7. Optionally, pause while waiting for the user to acknowledge the message.

and then [pause spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#pause):

> 1. If necessary, update the rendering or user interface of any Document or browsing context to reflect the current state.
> 2. Wait until the condition goal is met. While a user agent has a paused task, the corresponding event loop must not run further tasks, and any script in the currently running task must block. User agents should remain responsive to user input while paused, however, albeit in a reduced capacity since the event loop will not be doing anything.

alert should not block rendering (UI may be refreshed during pause), and theoretically it doesn't need to block any subsequent JS code while waiting for user (as spec says that pause is optional).

However, browsers are not always following specification (and in the case of pausing, experiments are allowed and encouraged), so I decided to test your code on several browsers I had available on current machine (Win7):

```
|-------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
|             |                     |                       |
|   browser   |  blocks UI refresh  |  executes subsequent  |
|             |     during alert    |   code during alert   |
|             |                     |                       |
|-------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
| Chrome 69.0 |         yes         |          no*          |
|-------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
| Opera 55.0  |         yes         |          no           |
|-------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
| FF Dev 63.0 |         no          |          no           |
|-------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
| FF 62.0     |         no          |          no           |
|-------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
| FF 60.2     |         no          |          no           |
|-------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
| FF 52.9     |         no          |          no           |
|-------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
| IE 11       |         no          |          no           |
|-------------|---------------------|-----------------------|
```

As you can see from above table, I encountered described problem only in Chrome and Opera (same rendering engine, both in currently latest stable version). None of tested browsers will run any subsequent JS code during alert, however Chrome appears to push callbacks of input events into call stack, if these events are triggered before displaying first alert (`*`). E.g. if you manage to click on your table cell more than once fast enough, function `cellClicked` will be invoked more times (so if you confirm first alert, Chrome will update UI state and display another alert). Any other browser from table doesn't seem to have this behavior though.

### Possible solutions

The most straightforward solution to avoid potential unwanted block of pending UI update is giving browser time to perform updates before blocking code will be executed. This can be achieved by moving alert and subsequent code into asynchronous callback, e.g. by using `setTimeout` function. In following snippet, I have moved calling of alert "Checking for win ..." and `checkWin()` in function `redrawArena` into callback of `setTimeout` function added there. This will allow browsers refresh your table before any alert is displayed, and thus bypassing unwanted UI blocking effect in affected browsers. You can also play with *delay* parameter of setTimeout to find minimal value that will allow to trigger UI refresh in all targeted browsers.

```css
.huntertable tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.huntertable td {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rabbit Hunters</title>

    <script>
      var size = 5;
      var hunters = new Array();

      function hunter(row, col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
      }

      function resetArena() {
        hunters = [];
        redrawArena();
      }

      function generate_table() {
        // get the reference for the body
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
        var tbl = document.createElement("table");
        tbl.setAttribute("class", "huntertable");
        var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        // creating all cells
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          // creates a table row
          var row = document.createElement("tr");

          for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
            // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
            // the end of the table row
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.addEventListener("click", cellClicked);
            cell.bgColor = "green";
            cell.innerHTML = "O";
            row.appendChild(cell);
          }

          // add the row to the end of the table body
          tblBody.appendChild(row);
        }

        // put the <tbody> in the <table>
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        // appends <table> into <body>
        body.appendChild(tbl);
        // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
        tbl.setAttribute("border", "5");
      }

      function cellClicked() {

        var cellRow = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var cellCol = this.cellIndex;
        var cHunter = new hunter(cellRow, cellCol);

        if (exists(cHunter)) {
          // remove the hunter 
          remove(cHunter);

        } else {

          if (hunters.length == 5) {
            alert("A maximum of 5 hunters are allowed!");
            return;
          }

          hunters.push(cHunter);
          redrawArena();
        }
      }

      function exists(hunter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < hunters.length; i++) {
          if ((hunters[i].row == hunter.row) && (hunters[i].col == hunter.col))
            return true;
        }
        return false;

      }

      function remove(hunter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < hunters.length; i++) {
          if ((hunters[i].row == hunter.row) && (hunters[i].col == hunter.col)) {
            hunters.splice(i, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
        redrawArena();
      }

      function redrawArena() {

        var arenaTable = document.getElementsByTagName("tbl")[0];
        var arenaTBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        // reset arena
        for (var rowi = 0; rowi < size; rowi++) {
          for (var coli = 0; coli < size; coli++) {
            rRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[rowi];
            rCell = rRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[coli];
            rCell.innerHTML = "O";
            rCell.bgColor = "green";
          }
        }

        for (var hunterIndex = 0; hunterIndex < hunters.length; hunterIndex++) {
          // for each hunter mark the attacked territory:
          hunterRow = hunters[hunterIndex].row;
          hunterCol = hunters[hunterIndex].col;

          huntRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow];
          huntCell = huntRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol];
          huntCell.innerHTML = "H";
          huntCell.bgColor = "red";

          // horizontal and vertical
          for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            hRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow];
            hCell = hRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[i];
            hCell.bgColor = "red";

            vRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
            vCell = vRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol];
            vCell.bgColor = "red";
          }

          // diagonals
          for (var i = 1; i < size; i++) {

            if (((hunterRow + i) < size) && ((hunterCol + i) < size)) {
              dRow1 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow + i];
              dCell1 = dRow1.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol + i];
              dCell1.bgColor = "red";
            }

            if (((hunterRow - i) >= 0) && ((hunterCol - i) >= 0)) {
              dRow2 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow - i];
              dCell2 = dRow2.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol - i];
              dCell2.bgColor = "red";
            }

            if (((hunterRow + i) < size) && ((hunterCol - i) >= 0)) {
              dRow3 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow + i];
              dCell3 = dRow3.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol - i];
              dCell3.bgColor = "red";
            }

            if (((hunterRow - i) >= 0) && ((hunterCol + i) < size)) {
              dRow4 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow - i];
              dCell4 = dRow4.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol + i];
              dCell4.bgColor = "red";
            }
          }
        }
        
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert("Checking for win ...");
          checkWin();
         },20);
      }
      
      function checkWin() {
        // check arena for 5 hunters and 3 rabbits...
        if (hunters.length < 5)
         return;
          
    var arenaTable = document.getElementsByTagName("tbl")[0];
    var arenaTBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        var rabbits = 0;
        for (var rowi = 0; rowi < size; rowi++) {
          for (var coli = 0; coli < size; coli++) {
            rRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[rowi];
            rCell = rRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[coli];
            if (rCell.bgColor == "green") {
             rabbits++;            
            }
             
          }
        }
        if (rabbits == 3)
         alert("Congrats! You did it!")
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="generate_table()">
    <h1>Rabbit Hunters</h1>
    <p>
      <ol>
        <li>The grid below represents a forest filled with rabbits (green).</li>
        <li>Hunters can attack horizontally and diagonally in all directions (like a chess queen).</li>
        <li>Once placed, hunters will kill all rabbits in their lines of sight (try clicking!).</li>
        <li>To remove hunters just click on them again.</li>
        <li>The Reset button clears the whole forest.</li>
      </ol>
      <strong>Can you place 5 hunters on the grid below so that they spare 3 rabbits (three green squares should remain)?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetArena()" />
    </p>
  </body>

</html>
```

However, in most cases (like yours), it is better to display such a kind of output directly into document. This way, your message will be displayed alongside other changes in DOM on next UI refresh. With the help of HTML, CSS and JS you can create your personal method for displaying messages (including custom modals, infobars, etc.). In below snippet, I have created very simple example, how can your app output messages to user. Basically, I have added additional div for displaying messages, created two functions for showing/removing messages in this div (`showMessage`/`removeMessage`) and replaced alerts with showMessage calls (and removed pointless alert "Checking for win ...").

```css
.huntertable tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.huntertable td {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#infobar {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rabbit Hunters</title>

    <script>
      var size = 5;
      var hunters = new Array();

      function hunter(row, col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
      }
      
      function showMessage(msgText) {
        var infobar = document.getElementById('infobar');
        infobar.innerHTML = msgText;
        infobar.style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
      
      function removeMessage() {
        var infobar = document.getElementById('infobar');
        infobar.innerHTML = '';
        infobar.style.visibility = null;
      }
      
      function resetArena() {
        removeMessage();
        hunters = [];
        redrawArena();
      }

      function generate_table() {
        // get the reference for the body
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

        // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
        var tbl = document.createElement("table");
        tbl.setAttribute("class", "huntertable");
        var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        // creating all cells
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          // creates a table row
          var row = document.createElement("tr");

          for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
            // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
            // the end of the table row
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.addEventListener("click", cellClicked);
            cell.bgColor = "green";
            cell.innerHTML = "O";
            row.appendChild(cell);
          }

          // add the row to the end of the table body
          tblBody.appendChild(row);
        }

        // put the <tbody> in the <table>
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        // appends <table> into <body>
        body.appendChild(tbl);
        // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
        tbl.setAttribute("border", "5");
      }

      function cellClicked() {
        removeMessage();
        
        var cellRow = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var cellCol = this.cellIndex;
        var cHunter = new hunter(cellRow, cellCol);

        if (exists(cHunter)) {
          // remove the hunter 
          remove(cHunter);

        } else {

          if (hunters.length == 5) {
            showMessage("A maximum of 5 hunters are allowed!");
            return;
          }

          hunters.push(cHunter);
          redrawArena();
        }
      }

      function exists(hunter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < hunters.length; i++) {
          if ((hunters[i].row == hunter.row) && (hunters[i].col == hunter.col))
            return true;
        }
        return false;

      }

      function remove(hunter) {
        for (var i = 0; i < hunters.length; i++) {
          if ((hunters[i].row == hunter.row) && (hunters[i].col == hunter.col)) {
            hunters.splice(i, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
        redrawArena();
      }

      function redrawArena() {

        var arenaTable = document.getElementsByTagName("tbl")[0];
        var arenaTBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        // reset arena
        for (var rowi = 0; rowi < size; rowi++) {
          for (var coli = 0; coli < size; coli++) {
            rRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[rowi];
            rCell = rRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[coli];
            rCell.innerHTML = "O";
            rCell.bgColor = "green";
          }
        }

        for (var hunterIndex = 0; hunterIndex < hunters.length; hunterIndex++) {
          // for each hunter mark the attacked territory:
          hunterRow = hunters[hunterIndex].row;
          hunterCol = hunters[hunterIndex].col;

          huntRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow];
          huntCell = huntRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol];
          huntCell.innerHTML = "H";
          huntCell.bgColor = "red";

          // horizontal and vertical
          for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            hRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow];
            hCell = hRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[i];
            hCell.bgColor = "red";

            vRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
            vCell = vRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol];
            vCell.bgColor = "red";
          }

          // diagonals
          for (var i = 1; i < size; i++) {

            if (((hunterRow + i) < size) && ((hunterCol + i) < size)) {
              dRow1 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow + i];
              dCell1 = dRow1.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol + i];
              dCell1.bgColor = "red";
            }

            if (((hunterRow - i) >= 0) && ((hunterCol - i) >= 0)) {
              dRow2 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow - i];
              dCell2 = dRow2.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol - i];
              dCell2.bgColor = "red";
            }

            if (((hunterRow + i) < size) && ((hunterCol - i) >= 0)) {
              dRow3 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow + i];
              dCell3 = dRow3.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol - i];
              dCell3.bgColor = "red";
            }

            if (((hunterRow - i) >= 0) && ((hunterCol + i) < size)) {
              dRow4 = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[hunterRow - i];
              dCell4 = dRow4.getElementsByTagName("td")[hunterCol + i];
              dCell4.bgColor = "red";
            }
          }
        }
        checkWin();
      }
      
      function checkWin() {
        // check arena for 5 hunters and 3 rabbits...
        if (hunters.length < 5)
         return;
          
    var arenaTable = document.getElementsByTagName("tbl")[0];
    var arenaTBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        var rabbits = 0;
        for (var rowi = 0; rowi < size; rowi++) {
          for (var coli = 0; coli < size; coli++) {
            rRow = arenaTBody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[rowi];
            rCell = rRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[coli];
            if (rCell.bgColor == "green") {
             rabbits++;            
            }
             
          }
        }
        if (rabbits == 3)
         showMessage("Congrats! You did it!");
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="generate_table()">
    <h1>Rabbit Hunters</h1>
    <p>
      <ol>
        <li>The grid below represents a forest filled with rabbits (green).</li>
        <li>Hunters can attack horizontally and diagonally in all directions (like a chess queen).</li>
        <li>Once placed, hunters will kill all rabbits in their lines of sight (try clicking!).</li>
        <li>To remove hunters just click on them again.</li>
        <li>The Reset button clears the whole forest.</li>
      </ol>
      <strong>Can you place 5 hunters on the grid below so that they spare 3 rabbits (three green squares should remain)?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetArena()" />
    </p>
    <div id="infobar"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

### TL;DR

In general, you should avoid using JS alerts neither for displaying usual textual output from your app, nor for debugging it. Alerts may prevent UI refresh in some browsers until they are confirmed by user, and also they may be blocked by browser, making them unreliable for displaying important information. If you need to display messages to user, you should create one or more methods for displaying them dynamically in document (you can actually find many different solutions over the web). For debugging, you should use Dev Tools panel integrated in every modern browser and methods from [Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) object. If you still insist on using alerts in your app, and you are experiencing unwanted blocking of page UI refresh or unrelated code because of them, you will probably need to put them into asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I was considering adding the messages as part of the document itself, rather than an alert, and with you recommending that as well, will go ahead!